# Tkinter only works once

Tags: python, tkinter

My problem is that the first time I run the program it works properly, but when I modify my query and hit the "Go!" button again, nothing happens. I wish it did the same so that when I entered a new query it reloaded the text box with the information corresponding to the last query.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

#Here's an entry box
search_label = Label(root, text="Enter search here:")
search_entry = Entry(root)
search_label.pack()
search_entry.pack()

#This happens when you hit "go!"
def go():
    #It opens a text box in which the answer required is written.
    query=search_entry.get()
    bibliography = Text(root)
    bibliography.insert(INSERT, answer_box(query))
    bibliography.pack()

#This is the "go!" button
go_button = Button(root, text="Go!", width=10, command=go)
go_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Some ideas?

Comment: `answer_box` is undefined - I take it this is not your full code?  Also, when I replace `answer_box(query)` with `query`, I can get it to run, but repeated uses of the `go_button` DOES result in new text boxes being added below with the new query text.  Are you sure nothing is happening?  Could it be happening off your screen?  Also, do you mean to be creating a new text box every time you hit the `go_button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates text widget every time the button is clicked. Instead of it, create the text widget only once. Then, clear it and insert the answer text.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

search_label = Label(root, text="Enter search here:")
search_entry = Entry(root)
search_label.pack()
search_entry.pack()

def answer_box(query):
    return query

def go():
    query=search_entry.get()
    bibliography.delete('1.0', END)
    bibliography.insert(INSERT, answer_box(query))

go_button = Button(root, text="Go!", width=10, command=go)
go_button.pack()
bibliography = Text(root)
bibliography.pack()

root.mainloop()
```